# Use JS array in rules property of Bootstrap form validation

Tags: validation, rules

I want to use my custom built JS array within rules: {} property of validate function below? Any ideas? I'm looking for a pure JS solution to this, no php or else.

Its a perfectly working function and have no issues with its functionality. All I want is to use an array instead of fields separately.

```
$(formId).validate({
    rules: {
        country_id: {
            required: true
        },
        state_id: {
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            alert(error);
            error.insertBefore(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }

    },
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length) {
            var s = errorList.shift();
            var n = [];
            n.push(s);
            this.errorList = n;
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        submitted = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand *"use my custom built JS array within rules: {} property of validate function below"*. *"All I want is to use an array instead of fields separately"* - If you want it to use then just use it :) and then ask a question if you stuck with a real and certain problem. How can we know what is `validate` function, what it does, and other things.

Comment: I'm trying it, but it doesn't works.

Comment: If you don't know about a validate function, obviously you shouldn't understood this in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here which is quite interesting.

I'd to create a JS object dynamically and then bind that object to the rules property, which did the job. Yay!!!!

```
var rules = new Object();
$(arrayRequiredField).each(function (index, value) {
        var fieldId = arrayRequiredField[index][0];
        var str = "rules." + fieldId + "= { required : true }" ;
        if(arrayRequiredField[index][1]=='Empty'){
            eval(str);
        }
});
$(formId).validate({
    rules: rules,
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            alert(error);
            error.insertBefore(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }

    },
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length) {
            var s = errorList.shift();
            var n = [];
            n.push(s);
            this.errorList = n;
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        submitted = true;
    }
});
```